# I am using MacBook Pro 13 .current OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos

How to upgrade the current OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)to “ high Sierra”

As the current os ( X El Capitan) is very old not supporting few features.

Anandarao n

Comment: Download High Sierra from the Apps Store and install. See [How to get old versions of macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) for a link to download.

Comment: What does the 13 mean? What model year is your MacBook Pro?

Comment: Please have a look at the tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour. Please **edit** your question and don't add this information as an answer.

Comment: Please *edit* your question to add additional information (don't post it below).

Answer (score 0):

Full macOS 10.xx updates (i.e. the Update that gets a new name) can be retrieved from the AppStore, yet instead of looking for it in Updates you need to search for them.

Usually however, you only get the newest compatible OS shown in AppStore so you'd need to visit [Apples website](https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT211683) to retrieve e.g. HighSierra.

As @davidanderson has pointed out you can find a [more detailed list of Apples OS updates and installers here on AD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: OS X El Capitan App Store... search column ... unable to retrieve macOS high Sierra...need help

Comment: Please read carefully every sentence of my answer and you will find that the blue text means there are links you can click. Further, you'll find all you need if you read through those support pages.